# SMIRK LINES, for example

Tags: word-request

What is the name of the lines from the bottom of the nose to the corners of the mouth?  Like when someone smirks.

Answer (score 1):

They are commonly called *laugh lines* or sometimes *smile lines*.

See [Collins definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laugh-lines).

The proper, anatomical name for them is *nasolabial folds*.

From [Wikipiedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasolabial_fold):

> The nasolabial folds, commonly known as "smile lines" or "laugh lines", are facial features.

Comment: That definition talks about the wrinkles next to a person's eyes.

Comment: @userr2684291 true, but in the example it describes lines going all the way down to a person's beard, so it can't be talking exclusively about the lines next to the eyes, which are usually referred to as "*crow's feet*". Evidently all lines produced from smiling / laughing come under this term. If you Google "laugh lines" you'll mainly see pictures of mouths.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I looked up "laugh lines" and "nasolabial folds" popped up. That's what I was trying to find. Thank you both.

Comment: @BadgerDown I've added that into my answer. To be clear, "nasolabial folds" is not a commonly used term as indicated by the fact no native English speakers came up with it for you. It is the proper, medical term. If your aim is to use it in a formal, educational context then by all means use that term. In everyday speech though, use "laugh lines".